# Generating/Downloading Docs in Java Applet

Tags: java, pdf, applet, download, certificate

I currently have a finance calculator applet that at the users request generates a PDF of the information calculated for the user. When it is generated, the PDF is created locally, and a JFileChooser allows the user to move the PDF to the destination on their machine of their choosing.

A certificate is required for the JFileChooser to run. What can I do to deliver the PDF to the user as an alternative to the JFileChooser and signing the applet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the official [Java Applet tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/security.html):

> When launched by using JNLP, unsigned applets can also perform the
>   following operations:
>
> ```
> * They can open, read, and save files on the client.
> ```

Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/doingMoreWithRIA/usingJNLPAPI.html) out as an example.

If you have to stick to traditional applets, you should sign the jar, even if that means self-signing (I think in this case a warning is displayed, but the user can proceed).

Comment: See also this [demo. of the JNLP API file services](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#fs).

Comment: The applet did not execute the code attempting to access the file system, but after self-signing, it now does.

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
URL url = new URL(getCodeBase().getProtocol(),
                      getCodeBase().getHost(),
                      getCodeBase().getPort(),
                      "/your_pdf_file");

getAppletContext().showDocument(url);
```

It would just prompt the user to download the file or view it inline

EDIT: This is only useful if the Server is generating the PDF and not the Client Applet

Comment: According to the question the PDF is created by the applet and isn't stored on the server.

Comment: I have mistaken locally as in the Owners Server, my bad.